# Can a person be a direct object?

Tags: direct-objects

Is "him" a direct object in the sentence:

"They sent him to prison."?

Several online sources claim that direct object answers the question "What?"

But it seems that it is not always the case.

Comment: A person can indeed be a direct object.

Comment: You might enjoy our sister site: [ell.se].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, a person can certainly be the direct object.

The question it answers is "what or whom?".

See also http://www.grammaruntied.com/blog/?p=671

> The direct object is the noun that receives the action of the transitive verb.

And they give an example:

> The police have arrested **the man** who committed the robberies.

Comment: Another example: In *The judge sent the prison a new inmate that afternoon,* the prison is the indirect object and the person the direct object.

Answer (score 1):

Online grammars are not always reliable. Often they have only half the problem, often they are imprecise, and sometimes there are errors. The best is to have a reliable grammar in book form. With online grammars alone it is difficult to get insight into grammar things. After a direct object you ask: Whom or what?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course. Example

> we have sent him to receive a parcel/any kind of thing you may consider.

Comment: Absolutely, but you'd need an article before the 'parcel' bit :)